# Contemporary research: are we moving in a right direction?

Tags: research-process

I have been thinking about this question and it is trying to make me less likely focused on my own research problems.

Can we see the contemporary research as follows:

- In the past, some research problem was solved.
- Because, of that solution of the past, a new research problem arose very recently.
- Now, we are trying to solve that.
- Repeat...

Is it what a research should be?

Consider the example of making the world digitized -- because of which security problems arose -- then now we are working on trying to make things secure by designing new algorithms. Then why did we solve the problem at the first place?

By generating new technologies, are we not making our life complex? Finally, we need peace in life -- Not a dumb smartphone beeping every time in our pocket to remind of something to do.

**Are we moving in a right direction?** [just curious to see responses]

Comment: I flagged this as off-topic for being primarily-opinion based.

Comment: And too broad as well.

Comment: instead of flagging as off-topic. why not move to chat? @Ian_Fin

Comment: @coder A question cannot be moved to chat, but you can certainly go to chat and propose a topic of discussion, though there are usually not many users there.

Comment: To speak about a different product of scientific research: has penicillin also made our life unnecessarily complex, in your opinion? It was much simpler back in the days: you get pneumonia, you die; that's it.

Comment: See the [help/dont-ask].

Comment: I don't think that the example you provided fits the question you ask. The new problem is not a new research problem, it is showing that the solution we found for the old problem is not good. Which means we have to improve it....

Answer (score 6):

By definition, **science** is about **accumulation and organization of knowledge**. Period. It's not about usability or new technology.

E.g., the technology around smartphones and mobility is more about engineering than about knowledge.  Some people even argue that technological patents are a means to decelerate scientific progress.  Others still call such technology science to get public money. Let's not mess with it - it's their problem or their luck.

Moreover, the world is not black-or-white. Between pure science and pure engineering a lot of niches exist on their own right. But again, when hearing the words "research" or "science", we should keep the above definition in mind.

Comment: +1 I like this answer. I retracted my close vote because of this answer. Sometimes, a bad question gets good answers.

Comment: The question doesn't ask about _science_ specifically. It asks about _research_, which happens in science, engineering, medicine, education, ...

Comment: I think that this answer just shows a poor understanding of what's behind smartphones and how much reciprocal contamination there is between science and engineering.

Comment: When we have these many contradicting points. Why to make it off-topic?

Comment: @Coder It's exactly because there can be so many contradicting points that the question is off-topic. The format of SE is not suited for a discussion, but only to well-defined questions to which practical answers can be given (do this, do that). Though here, on Academia.SE, we are somewhat more open than other SE communities, and I like this, we have to accept that the way SE site are structured is unsuitable for these kind of discussions. A forum would be more suitable.

Comment: @LeonMeier I see that you have softened a bit your answer with respect to the first version, but I think that there are still two issues: the first is that engineering _is_ knowledge, as more than one hundred years of history have shown; the second is that technology is useful to anybody, from "scientists" (should they really be any different from engineers) to the layperson: why, as your answer seems to imply, shouldn't they get public money?

Comment: "Abstraction is seldom employed in engineering": To produce concrete objects many engineers have employed, and are employing, abstraction. To remain in the field of telecommunications, information theory, coding theory and quantization theory emerged from the need of transmitting and manipulating data in an efficient way. Not to mention the cross-contamination between physics, engineering electromagnetics and mathematics.